# select all Li inside a div

Tags: jquery, css, list, menu, background

I need to set background color on all li item inside a div. I am having hard time  getting to the list item because of the mess sharepoint creates when the li are rendered. Each li are the result of a sharepoint server control render. This is essentially a top navigation with 6 menu items horizontally laid out and some of them even have sub menu items.

I need to set a bgcolor on all list items and change bg color on hover and change back to the original color on mouseout.

```
<div id="zz16_HDRNav" class="s4-tn">
    <div class="menu horizontal menu-horizontal">
        <ul class="root static">
            <li class="static">
                <a class="static menu-item" href="/">
                    <span class="additional-background">
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Home</span></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="static dynamic-children">
                <a class="static dynamic-children menu-item" href="/finance">
                    <span class="additional-background">
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Employee Center</span></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dynamic">
                    <li class="dynamic">
                        <a class="dynamic menu-item" href="/finance/EMEA"><span class="additional-background">
                            <span class="menu-item-text">Benefits</span></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dynamic">
                        <a class="dynamic menu-item" href="/finance/APAC"><span class="additional-background">
                            <span class="menu-item-text">Travel</span></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dynamic">
                        <a class="dynamic menu-item" href="/finance/CORP">
                            <span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">TSO</span></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="static">
                <a class="static menu-item" href="/team">
                    <span class="additional-background">
                    <span class="menu-item-text">Business Communities</span></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="static dynamic-children">
                <span class="static dynamic-children menu-item"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Internal Services</span></span></span>
                <ul class="dynamic">
                    <li class="dynamic">
                        <a class="dynamic menu-item" href="/regions/NA">
                            <span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">North America</span></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dynamic">
                        <a class="dynamic menu-item" href="/regions/me">
                            <span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Middle East</span></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="static">
                <a class="static menu-item" href="/it">
                    <span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Best Practices</span></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="static">
                <a class="static menu-item" href="/legal">
                    <span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">PolicyProcedures</span></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use some straight CSS for that:

```
#zz16_HDRNav>.menu>ul>li
{
    background-color:gray;
}
#zz16_HDRNav>.menu>ul>li :hover
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/XgExk/7/

Answer (score 2):

this will set background color of all li inside your div

```
$('#YourdivId').find('li').hover(function () {
                            $(this).css({ 'background-color': 'gray' });
                        }, function () { $(this).css({ 'background-color': '' }); });
```

Answer (score 2):

in css:

```
#zz16_HDRNav li{
       background-color: your color;
}

#zz16_HDRNav li:hover{
       background-color: your color;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use `hover()` method and utilize a class for your hover styles. Something like this:

```
$("#zz16_HDRNav li").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('yourHoverClass');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('yourHoverClass');
    }
);
```

That is jQuery solution, though I personally try to use straight CSS for hover conditions as noted in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do that with jQuery and not CSS, I would do that with a class:

```
$('div li').css({'background-color':'red'})
       .hover(function(){ 
             $(this).toggleClass('hover')
             });
```

and then in the css:

```
.hover{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should deal with the first level LI items:

```
div.s4-tn div.menu ul.root li.static {
    background-color:red;
}

div.s4-tn div.menu ul.root li.static:hover {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
ul.dynamic {display:none}
.root li { width:auto; float:left; margin:4px; display:block;}
.menu { width:780px}
.yourclass { background:#ffbbcc; color:#aaffcc;}
.root li.dynamic { width:100px; clear:left}
li.dynamic:hover { background:#aaffcc;color:#ffbbcc;}
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery('li.static').live('hover', function() {
    jQuery('li.static').find("ul.dynamic").hide();
    jQuery('li.static').removeClass('yourclass');       
    jQuery(this).addClass('yourclass');
    jQuery(this).find("ul.dynamic").show();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vitrum/nHgWe/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Why use jQuery? Just use CSS:

```
div li {
background-color:#CCC;
}

div li:hover {
background-color: #AAA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick! http://jsfiddle.net/BnJ3G/2/

Cheers